# Does sysadmin enthusiast mean in english?

Tags: phrases

I'm not a native English speaker. I wonder does the phrase "SysAdmin Enthusiast" mean? any role + Enthusiast. like Developer Enthusiast, Manager Enthusiast etc.
I just had a discussion with one of my friends which he is not a native speaker too and he insists on using this phrase. SysAdmin is just a role. mean System Administration. a role in an organization.

Edit1:
Sysadmin is a role that means System Admin and he/she do system administration.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask on [SuperUser SE](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Enthusiastic Systems Administrator would work better. I can belive in (because I have known some) IT enthusiasts, C++ enthusiasts, Javascript enthusiasts and enthusiasts in many other fields but System Administration enthusiasts seem unlikely as you have to be working in a complex IT environment to _be_ a Systems Administrator so it's difficult, if not impossible, to do it as a hobby.

Comment: Perhaps a longer quote with "sysadmin enthusiast" in it would help determine its meaning.

Answer (score -1):

> **enthusiast** noun
>
> a : one who is ardently attached to a cause, object, or pursuit
>  // a sports car enthusiast
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enthusiast

A SysAdmin enthusiast would be a person who is attached to, that is, who cares very much about, system administration.

Note that *system administration* is not a role, it's an activity. It is unusual to describe someone as a [some role] enthusiast. Usually, we describe people as an [activity] enthusiast, or a [type of object] enthusiast, as in *skiing [activity] enthusiast* or *sports car [type of object] enthusiast*.

It would be a little strange to describe someone as a *skier enthusiast* or a *cigar smoker enthusiast*.  These phrases make sense, but they would describe a person who like skiers, or cigar smokers, and not a person likes to ski or likes cigars.

Comment: I work with a cigar smok*ing* enthusiast - which is a similar but much more natural construction to one of your examples. An *enthusiast sysadmin* would be a keen amateur, but doesn't seem quite right - unlike  with gardener or woodworker

Comment: Yes, system administration enthusiast makes sense but SysAdmin is a role of System Administration in IT as I Know.

Comment: In British usage, maybe elsewhere also, an 'enthusiast' is often used of someone who has a strong interest in some professional field, but without actually being employed in it. The classic example is the railway enthusiast (I am one myself).

Comment: It could also mean a system administrator who is also an enthusiast.